# custom annotation on RequestParam and PathVariable

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-webflux, aop, annotation-processing

I have created a custom annotation

```
annotation class UserControl(
    val userIdentifier: String
)
```

I wan to apply this annotation on query parameters, and path variables in different controllers.

```
    fun userWithMobile(
        @UserControl("PhoneNumber")
        @RequestParam mobile: String
    ): RegisteredUser {
        return userManager.getUserWithPhoneNumber(mobile))
    }
```

How can i check if the query parameters have the UserControl annotation or not, and do some processing on that. Is there standard way to write a global handler , or a processor for that?

Would appreciate any help

Comment: this is usually done using spring aspects, https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop

Answer (score 0):

AspectJ can directly match parameter annotations, but not bind them to advice method values like class or method annotations. So if you only want to match them, a simple pointcut is enough. If you want to access the annotations and maybe their parameter values, you need a little bit of reflection magic. I have answered related questions many times already, which is why I am going to close this one as a duplicate. But first, here are the resources you want to read. They all related to your question, showing examples of how to handle different specific situations:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38162279/1082681
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10595712/1082681
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50540489/1082681
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49872132/1082681
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61284425/1082681
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16624766/1082681

Basically, the pointcut you want the following or some variation of it:

```java
execution(* *(.., @my.package.UserControl (*), ..))
```

The naive, less efficient approach without matching the parameter in the pointcut, using only relfection:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27784714/1082681
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42561014/1082681

Comment: Thanks for all the resources. Can this also be used to modify the annotated request parameter?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with AOP. But that is a different question. You should be able to find the answer here via search. If not, which would surprise me, feel free to ask a new question. But before you do that, please accept and upvote my answer if you agree that I answered your original question.

Comment: I think you forgot to accept + upvote my answer.